# Rails modify only specifi key on yaml file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this yaml file in my rails app:

```
common: &common
  host: 'api.example.com'
  social_media:
    secret: 'omglolthisissecret'
  snap:
    host: "https://app.example.com/money/v1/transactions"

development:
  <<: *common

test:
  <<: *common

production:
  <<: *common
```

I need to set different value for `snap.host` key, let say the value should be:

```
https://sandbox.example.com/money/v1/transactions
```

How do I do that? thanks in advance.

Comment: is it `host.snap` or `snap.host` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why putting it to defaults if that's changing for environments? :)

Anyway, to override a value you should, well, override it:

```
common: &common
  host: 'api.example.com'
  social_media:
    secret: 'omglolthisissecret'
  snap:
    host: "https://app.example.com/money/v1/transactions"

development:
  <<: *common
  snap:
    host: 'devhost'

test:
  <<: *common
  snap:
    host: 'testhost'

production:
  <<: *common
  snap:
    host: 'prodhost'
```

**Note**: If `snap` contains other fields in defaults, such override would delete them, so while overriding you have to repeat all fields.

Comment: Whoa :o it works, thanks, the key actually is more than what I already mentioned above :) and all of them almost share the same value except for snap host

Comment: If snap contained other fields in defaults, this env override would delete them.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev thanks for this note! Edited the answer :)

Comment: @AndreyDeineko: my pleasure :) I once had to rewrite a fairly complex config file from yaml to ruby because of this.

Answer (score 1):

Override it in desired environment

```
common: &common
  host: 'api.example.com'
  social_media:
    secret: 'omglolthisissecret'
  snap:
    host: "https://app.example.com/money/v1/transactions"

development:
  <<: *common
  snap:
    host: "https://sandbox.example.com/money/v1/transactions"

test:
  <<: *common
  snap:
    host: "https://sandbox.example.com/money/v1/transactions"

production:
  <<: *common
```